# NUnits: Start automation tests parallel in a defined order (Selenium)

Tags: nunit

Im writing automation tests for our website using NUnit and Selenium.

We have 2 different users (`aminInt and hsuInt`) and 3 features which need to be tested (in the example below `TestA, TestB, TestC`)

In my example below, there are in total 6 automation tests in the test explorer as each feature is being tested with both users.

Everything works. Each test is getting its own webDriver and all the tests are independent.

Now i want to start the tests in parallel.

I already tried everything i could find online. Tried the different parameter in parallelizable, but i cant get it right.

I would like to start 2 test at a time.

For example:

```
First test:
TestA adminInt
TestA hsuInt
```

after both tests above are done, it should start:

```
Second Test:
TestB adminInt
TestB hsuInt
```

[image]

Comment: If the tests are completely independent as you say, why do you want them to run in a defined order?

Comment: To reduce the time when running the tests. Currently, i have 14 automated testcases and it takes over 2 minutes to finish all of them (The website is big).
I want to reduce the time by running 2 tests in parallel, which is possible when i test both test user (which are defined in the TestFixture) at the same time for each feature. Running all in parallel, takes much longer.

Comment: I added `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]` to only one test class (in the example its TestA), and its doing what i want. It starts the test for both users. But when i add this parameter to the other 2 classes, then all tests start again at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

I found a solution for how to start just 2 tests in parallel.

With this parameter in front of the class, only 2 tests will start in parallel.
`//[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(2)]` You need this parameter only inside of one class. So if you have different classes which have their own tests, add this parameter to only one class and it will run all tests in parallel as long as you have the fixture command too.

`[TestFixture("userA")]`
`[TestFixture("userB")]`

To start the test for 2 different users for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save  time and your tests are truly independent, then trying to control the order of execution isn't what you want. Essentially, it's NUnit's job to figure out **how** to run in parallel. Your job is merely to tell NUnit whether the tests you wrote are **capable** of running in parallel.

To tell NUnit which tests may be run in parallel, use the `[Non]ParallelizableAttribute`. If you place attributes on the fixtures, their different meaning is as follows...

`[NonParallelizable]` means that the fixture is *not capable* of running in parallel with any other fixtures. That's the default if you don't specify any attribute.

`[Parallelizable]` means that the fixture is *capable* of running in parallel with other fixtures in your test.

`[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]` means that both the fixture and all the individual tests under that fixture are *capable* of running in parallel.

`[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children]` means that the fixture is *not capable* of running in parallel with other fixtures but the test methods under it may run in parallel with one another.

I stressed *capable* above because that's what you should focus on. Don't use the attribute with the expectation that NUnit will run some tests together with other specific tests because there is no NUnit feature to do that. Keep your focus on what you can control... writing independent, parallelizable tests and telling NUnit which ones they are.

If you find that NUnit starts too many test threads at one time, you can place a [LevelOfParallelism](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/levelofparallelism.html) attribute in your AssemblyInfo.cs. However, keep in mind that NUnit defaults depending on the number of cores available. So what works for you on your development machine may not give the best performance in your CI builds. My advice is to let NUnit use its defaults for most things until you see a reason to override them.